# convert destinations airport codes to full names rstudio

Tags: r

I have two tables: one with airport codes and Airport dataframe with iata_code and name. I want to replace the airport codes to full names. I think to use iata_code column in Airport dataframe to find the vector of row indices in Airport, using %in% opreator. Using the vector of indices,  extract the name column in the relevant airport codes and save the vector of full names to my table.
here is my table:[image: my table]

and here is airports table:
[image]

thank you for your help

Comment: According to this forums guidelines you shouldn't post images of code or data, but add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Adding a MRE and an example of the desired output (in code form, not tables and pictures) makes it much easier for others to find and test a answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you! P.S. Here is [a good overview on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Join two data.frames:

```
new_df <- merge(first_table, airports_table, by.x="dest", by.y="iata_code")
```